# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found

Tags: java, exception

How to solve this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found:
 com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:775)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:861)
    at java.awt.Window.getToolkit(Window.java:1127)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:369)
    at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:407)
    at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:402)
    at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:367)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:163)
    at FirstJavaProject.(FirstJavaProject.java:7)
    at FirstJavaProject.main(FirstJavaProject.java:5)
```

It occurs during the execution of following program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TenButtons extends JFrame{

    JButton [] btns= new JButton[10];

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new TenButtons();
    }
    public TenButtons(){
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setTitle("10 Buttons");
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for(int i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
           btns[i]=new JButton("Button ");
           this.add(btns[i]);
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/accessibility.properties` file has the following content:

```
## Load the Java Access Bridge class into the JVM ##
assistive_technologies=com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
#screen_magnifier_present=true
```

Comment: accessibility.properties is available in the jre/lib folder

Comment: Thanks.
I found this, worked for me :) https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-error-while-building-aprof-plot

Comment: I found this solution, worked for me :) https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-error-while-building-aprof-plot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For future reference, one of the more common causes of this exception is a missing or corrupt installation of a [Java Access Bridge](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136191.html). In this case, the following access bridge has been defined in standard configuration file (`JDK_HOME/jre/lib/accessibility.properties`):

```
com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
```

But it won't actually be operative unless the required installation is complete. Note that the standard access bridge implementation *does not* come packages with the SDK. To fix your particular issue, download and install the Oracle Access Bridge by following instructions from their [setup page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm). That should resolve the startup error occurring in your program.

Comment: For Windows users that settings file can be found in users folder: `C:\Users\current_user\.accessibility.properties` So find it and delete or comment each line in that file by `#`

Answer (score 6):

Answer for those who:

- Are using Windows WSL2
- And have installed OpenJDK 8
- Have tried to start the Gremlin Console or likewise Java app

And received the same error of `Assistive technology not found AWTError` the previous approved answers are correct.

For WSL2 and OpenJDK 8 specifically here is what you need to do:

`sudo vim /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties`

Comment out the configuration line out like below:

`#assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper`

There is no need to restart WSL session. Simply re-launch the Java app.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone using jlink to create a minified JRE, you can fix this error by including the module "jdk.accessibility" in your list of required modules.

The files required for Access Bridge include the following:

```
/jre/bin/windowsaccessbridge-64.dll
/jre/bin/javaaccessbridge.dll
/jre/bin/jaccesswalker.exe
/jre/bin/jaccessinspector.exe 
/jre/lib/modules (jlink will include the accessibility module inside this file with the other modules)
```

Alternatively, you can disable Access Bridge using the command:

```
jre\bin\jabswitch.exe -disable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Java 11**, it is likely you are using **Java 8** and it does not have the **Assistive Technology** or **org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper**.

Also, do not comment out the assistive technology line from the accessibility properties file, this will not fix your problem rather it will misconfigure your layout and you will be left with an ugly or unusable UI.