# Persistent Netlogo Install Error

Tags: java, netlogo

I'm a student in high school with what I think is a decent knowledge of computers but almost no knowledge of Java. For my computer science class, we're learning Netlogo and I was asked to install it on my PC. I'm have an HP laptop running windows 8.1 (ew). Every time I try to install it with the regular installer with bundled java, I get the error message shown below
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: com.sunjava.accessibility.AccesBridge

So far I've tried a whole lot of things including:

- Uninstalling java and instlaling (nope)
- Reinstalling java and installing (no)
- I tried installing Java access bridge which i thought would fix it but i only have a rudimentary at best understanding of java so i could have messed that up but it didnt work
- Restarting my computer (always a classic alas, it didnt work)
- Installing older versions of java that might be compatible

^^ none of those worked for me so does anybody have any ideas as to what is going on and how I can fix it? I'll paste the log file below

```
Exception:
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
 at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:773)
 at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:872)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1063)
 at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1326)
 at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
 at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
 at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
 at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
System properties:
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
exe4j.moduleName=C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\NetLogo5.1.0Installer (1).exe
exe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_users_danny_downloads_netlogo5.1.0installer_(1).exe
sun.boot.library.path=c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\bin
java.vm.version=20.45-b01
java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/
exe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0
path.separator=;
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.country=US
sun.os.patch.level=
javax.accessibility.screen_magnifier_present=true
install4j.exeDir=C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j58DC.tmp_dir1417487409
java.runtime.version=1.6.0_45-b06
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\endorsed
os.arch=x86
javax.accessibility.assistive_technologies=com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\
line.separator=
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
user.variant=
exe4j.tempDir=C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j58DC.tmp_dir1417487409
os.name=Windows 8
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\bin
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=50.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
exe4j.isInstall4j=true
os.version=6.2
user.home=C:\Users\Danny
user.timezone=America/New_York
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding=Cp1252
java.specification.version=1.6
java.class.path=C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j58DC.tmp_dir1417487409\i4jruntime.jar;C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j58DC.tmp_dir1417487409\user.jar;C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j58DC.tmp_dir1417487409\platform.zip;
user.name=Danny
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
sun.java.command=C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\NetLogo5.1.0Installer (1).exe
java.home=c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre
sun.arch.data.model=32
exe4j.launchName=C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\NetLogo5.1.0Installer (1).exe
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
exe4j.unextractedPosition=22341342
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.ext.dirs=c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
sun.boot.class.path=c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\resources.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\jsse.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\jce.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\charsets.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;c:\users\danny\appdata\local\temp\e4j58dc.tmp_dir1417487409\jre\classes
install4j.appDir=C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
```

Comment: It's nearly certain that there is nothing NetLogo-specific about this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260989/exception-in-thread-main-java-awt-awterror-assistive-technology-not-found)

Comment: I tried following those instructions though and it didn't fix anything... Unless I did it wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lastest version of Java, then install NetLogo. Try using ADMIN priviledges.