# Charles proxy won't start. Assistive Technology not found: com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge

Tags: java, charles-proxy

My previous question was deleted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698763/charles-proxy-wont-open-assistive-technology-not-found-com-sun-java-accessibi) because it was considered as duplicate. I say it's not duplicate because the answers were about java itself while my question was about charles proxy and those answers didn't resolve my problem.

I had installed `jdk-17.0.1` and `jre1.8.0_311` on my machine when I tried to open `charles proxy 4.6.2` on double click but nothing happened, the application didn't start. I try to open via command prompt by typing `Charles.exe` and this error is shown

```
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at de.sciss.syntaxpane.DefaultSyntaxKit.<clinit>(DefaultSyntaxKit.java:105)
        at com.xk72.charles.gui.lib.UIUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.xk72.charles.gui.s.h(Unknown Source)
        at com.xk72.charles.gui.Main.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.xk72.charles.Main.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.xk72.charles.gui.Main.main(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.xk72.lib.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.xk72.charles.gui.MainWithClassLoader.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more
```

I'm using Windows 10 64bit. `%JAVA_HOME%` is also setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me going to `C:\Users\my account\.accessibility.properties` and commenting out every line by adding a `#` a front of it worked.(I at least don't need the accessibility)

Found this solution at: [Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260989/exception-in-thread-main-java-awt-awterror-assistive-technology-not-found#comment117751693_15263840)

Comment: You're correct. And if the problem persists mark the file as readonly

Comment: This was super helpful, thanks!  I'm investigating a way to handle this client-side without breaking older software which may require this file.